# Setting up SSL(https) in AWS Mean Stack hosted at EC2 using ngInx

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, mean-stack

I am trying to setup my website for SSL / https and I am doing steps as I see on Web but facing some problems. Please guide.

My steps that I did are:

1. Hosted my MEAN stack website at EC2 in AWS.
2. Both UI and Backend runs on Node server with Angular running as Angular Universal SSR.
3. Site name hosted on http://www.gabruism.com and gets the 'not secure' prompt.
4. My nginx configuration is this:

   server {
   charset utf-8;
   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name _;
   location / {
   Proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
   }
   location /api/ {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
   }
   }

   4000 runs Angular SSR on node server and 8080 runs Express backend on node server.
5. Then, I created the certificate from AWS Certificate Manager and verified it in DNS, added to CNAME in Route 53.
6. After that, I create Cloudfront in AWS for this certificate. I got this URL which loads my website at https BUT my http APIs dont work (known reason that it expects https APIs - how to resolve?).
   *https://da64unrkw26hn.cloudfront.net/home*
7. Now, my questions start. Please have a look.

As a full stack programmer, I created this whole MEAN stack website on my own and then hosted it on AWS. But, I am stuck at SSL now.

1. Am I doing over-engineering here to achieve SSL?
2. Question in simplest form: how do I enable SSL on MEAN website running on EC2 with above ngInx config (keeping in mind Angular code itself runs on node server as a part of Server Side Rendering)
3. What steps I did to achieve SSL till now are not needed and what more should be done?
4. How to make gabruism.com entry in route53 point to cloudfront url? Do I need to replace previous cname?

Please guide me as the various docs left me confused. Thanks.

Comment: It appears you still need to point the domain `www.gabruism.com` to the CloudFront distribution.

Comment: How do I do it Mark? In route53, do I replace earlier entries?

Comment: You would modify the current DNS entry for `www` in Route53.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `Step 5`

Instead of that follow this.

1. Go to Cloud front and open your distribution
2. In the General Tab click on the Edit button
3. In the Alternate Domain Names enter your domain names. In your case, it is [www.gabruism.com](http://www.gabruism.com) and gabruism.com. the second entry should be entered in a new line.
4. Click on 'Yes, Edit' at the bottom right corner.
5. Then Go to Route53 and select your hosted zone (Assuming you are using new UI for Route53)
6. Click on Create Record (top right button)
7. Select Simple Routing and click Next
8. Define Simple Record
9. Enter 'www' for the record name
10. FOr Value/Route traffic to select 'Alias to CloudFront Distribution'
11. Next Select your region and select your distribution
12. Leave the record type as 'A' and then click on 'Define Simple Record'
13. Repeat these steps 6-12 for one more record without a name, so that it will point to gabruism.com

Make sure that the alternative CNAME you've mentioned in CloudFront distribution matches the Route53 record name

Comment: Will try this today. Thanks.
How do I resolve point 6. Do I need to enter 443 in ngInx and change my APIs to call https version of URLs?

Comment: @SukhminderSinghParmar you should point your route53 A record to cloduformation

Comment: Thanks, let me do these steps this weekend and return with the inputs

Comment: I followed above steps.--
Now, https://gasbruism.com opens the secured site.-- Two issues that I am looking at: 1) from google.com, it opens the 'not secure' version still-- 2) NodeJs APIs are still failing with error: polyfills-es2015.e041970de26af10cd427.js:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://gabruism.com/blogs/list' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://ec2-18-216-206-82.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/api/api/blogs/getBlogs'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: UNless, I manually add https, it loads http.Thus, gabruism.com opens http. I guess it will take some time to reflect?? Will confirm. But, how do I resolve the API issue

Comment: Eg: this API( http://ec2-18-216-206-82.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/api/api/blogs/getBlogs ) works when directly called in browser. But this (https://ec2-18-216-206-82.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/api/api/blogs/getBlogs ) does not work.

Comment: Still, the default url opens as http rather than https.